# Automatic sum of 3 EditTexts in another EditText

Tags: android

I have 3 EditTexts - et1, et2, et3. I want to put the sum of them in another EditText, et33.

If the sum is 18, the background color of et33 will be green; if not, it will be red.

How can I do it? Here's what I have now:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
int y = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());
int z = Integer.parseInt(et3.getText().toString());
et33.setText(String.valueOf(x+y+z));
if (Summ(x, y, z) = 18) {
    //the background color et33 will be green
} else {
    //the background color et33 will be red
}
public int Summ(int x, int y, int z) {
    int sum = 0;

    sum = x + y + z;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Could you please make your question a bit more specific? Do you need help setting the background color of the "et33" TextView, or something else?

Comment: thinks et33 edittext in which is the sum of 3 edittext et1, et2, et3

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et1;
    EditText et2;
    EditText et3;
    EditText et33;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et3);
        et33 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et33);


        et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                    int x = (et1.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()) : 0;
                    int y = (et2.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString()) : 0;
                    int z = (et3.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et3.getText().toString()) : 0;
                    et33ColorChanged(x, y, z);

            }
        });

        et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                int x = (et1.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()) : 0;
                int y = (et2.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString()) : 0;
                int z = (et3.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et3.getText().toString()) : 0;
                et33ColorChanged(x, y, z);
            }
        });
        et3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                int x = (et1.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString()) : 0;
                int y = (et2.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString()) : 0;
                int z = (et3.getText().toString().length() != 0) ? Integer.parseInt(et3.getText().toString()) : 0;
                et33ColorChanged(x, y, z);
            }
        });

    }

    public void et33ColorChanged(int x, int y, int z) {
        et33.setText(String.valueOf(x + y + z));
        if ((x + y + z) == 18) {
            //the background color et33 will be green
            et33.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
        } else {
            //the background color et33 will be red
            et33.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));

        }
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that all your `EditText` should accept number only

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean this:

```
if (Summ(x, y, z) == 18) {
   et33.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
} else {
   et33.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `==`.